# Getting import error while loading CatBoostClassifier

Tags: python, importerror, catboost

installed catboost and ipywidgets still getting import error: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections'

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifire
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 14
     12 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, ExtraTreeClassifier
     13 from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
---> 14 from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
     16 from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
     17 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

File c:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\catboost\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .core import Pool, CatBoost, CatBoostClassifier, CatBoostRegressor, CatboostError, cv  # noqa
      2 try:
      3     from .widget import CatboostIpythonWidget  # noqa

File c:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py:4
      2 from six import iteritems, string_types
      3 import os.path
----> 4 from collections import Iterable, Sequence, Mapping, MutableMapping
      5 import warnings
      6 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (c:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: please use lower version python, 3.9 may be, `Iterable` is deprecated in 3.10

Comment: Thanks  for the suggestion .it works in 3.7, But is there any way we can use catboost in 3.11. there must be right ?